# How to use function of jquery in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a jquery function..

```
*function isCheckedById(id) {
  var checked = $("input[@id=" + id + "]:checked").length;

  if (checked == 0) {
    return false;
  }

else {
    return true;
  }
}*
```

And I want to use return the value of this function in my php code..

```
if ("checked") // checked
{

echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'.$brand_item->name.'" value="'.$brand_item->slug.'" checked><label for="'.$brand_item->term_id.'">'.$brand_item->slug.'</label>';

                    }
```

Help me, what parameter should I give to If statement so that I can use the value return by my jquery function. 
I am using these codes in wordpress, Please explain in details as I am completely new to these things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: Try and use `ajax`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like in your template file:

```
function isCheckedById(id) {
  var checked = $("input[@id=" + id + "]:checked").length;
  var html = '';
  if (checked == 0) {
    return false;
  }

else {
    return true;
  }
}

if(isCheckedById('checkit')){

    html = '<input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $brand_item->name; ?>" value="<?php echo $brand_item->slug; ?>" checked><label for="<?php echo $brand_item->term_id; ?>"><?php echo $brand_item->slug; ?></label>';
    $('#container').html(html);
}
```